# How to show multiple marks on google map v2

Tags: android

I want to show multiple marks on google map v2 on run time.I have location table on remote server which contain all latitude and longitude.
I want to read latitude and longitude to show marker against each entry in location table but I don't know It give place one marker on google map.....First values in case of list and If use hashMap then give last value in database
Here is my code that am using to read and show marker on google map.Please help m and thanks in advance

```
 public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
JSONArray jsonArray;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> prodArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> HashMap ;
String text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();



        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(32.634723, 74.1601851)).zoom(12).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        ActionStartsHere();



        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    ReadDriverLocation task1 = new ReadDriverLocation();
    task1.execute(new String[]{"http://ahsan.comyr.com/ReadLocation.php"});
}
//This method call thread ofter 10 second
public void ActionStartsHere() {
    CallBangroundClass();
}


public void CallBangroundClass() {
    new CountDownTimer(11000, 30000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            //Object of ReadActiveDriver Class extends with AsyncTask Class

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            ActionStartsHere();
        }

    }.start();
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private class ReadDriverLocation extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>
{
    String text = "";

    ArrayList<String> list;
    ArrayList<String> list1;
    ArrayList<String> list2;
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        InputStream inputStream;
        for(String url1: urls) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url1);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }

            BufferedReader reader;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = null;
                while((line = reader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    text += line +"\n";
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            HashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(text);

                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String lati = jsonObject.getString("latitude");
                    String longLat = jsonObject.getString("longitude");
                    String Time = jsonObject.getString("time");

                    list.add(lati);
                    list1.add(longLat);
                    list2.add(Time);
                   //HashMap.put("Latitude", lati);
                   //HashMap.put("Longitude", longLat);
                   //HashMap.put("time", Time);
                   //prodArrayList.add(HashMap);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result == true)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
            {
                Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(list.get(i));
                Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(list1.get(i));

                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).title(list2.get(i));
                // GREEN color icon
                mMap.addMarker(marker);
            }
            /*
            for(int i=0; i<prodArrayList.size(); i++)
            {
                HashMap<String,String> hMap = prodArrayList.get(i);
                Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(hMap.get("Latitude"));
                Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(hMap.get("Longitude"));

                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).title(hMap.get("time"));
                // GREEN color icon
                mMap.addMarker(marker);

            }*/
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Error in Loading...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: where is your google map fragment ?

Comment: I have just show backgound service code to get value and show on mark....Mark is shown on google map if manually added latitude and longitude

Comment: you want to put latitude and longitude in hashmap ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use HashMap then you are getting last value because you are using same HashMap object in your for loop. According to HashMap definition,if you use same key then prior value for the key is dropped and replaced with the new one.

HashMap = new HashMap();// This hashMap is used entire for loop

try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(text);

```
        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String lati = jsonObject.getString("latitude");
            String longLat = jsonObject.getString("longitude");
            String Time = jsonObject.getString("time");
           // You use here duplicate key hence last value retained by hash map
           HashMap.put("Latitude", lati);
           HashMap.put("Longitude", longLat);
           HashMap.put("time", Time);
           prodArrayList.add(HashMap);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In order to get right value from hashMap then create new instance for hashmap in for loop as follows :

```
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(text);

        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String lati = jsonObject.getString("latitude");
            String longLat = jsonObject.getString("longitude");
            String Time = jsonObject.getString("time");

            HashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

           HashMap.put("Latitude", lati);
           HashMap.put("Longitude", longLat);
           HashMap.put("time", Time);
           prodArrayList.add(HashMap);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Set your marker as follows :

```
for(int i=0; i<prodArrayList.size(); i++)
            {
                HashMap<String,String> hMap = prodArrayList.get(i);
                Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(hMap.get("Latitude"));
                Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(hMap.get("Longitude"));

                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).title(hMap.get("time"));
                // GREEN color icon
                mMap.addMarker(marker);

            }
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestions now It give me first value as marker on google map

Comment: how you get values from prodArrayList ? In your code, getting value from prodArrayList is commented.